# Scala interprets _ param as Any => [Any]

Tags: scala

I have an enum defined as follows

```
enum Operator[T](val expr: String, val tag: T):

  case Plus(override val tag: T) extends Operator("+", tag)
  case Minus(override val tag: T) extends Operator("-", tag)
  case Multiply(override val tag: T) extends Operator("*", tag)
```

Next is a function call that checks whether the passed list of operators starts with a certain operator or not

```
def extract[A](expect: Operator[A], operators: List[Operator[A]]): Either[Error[A], (Operator[A], List[Operator[A]])] =
  operators match {
    case `expect` :: tail  => Right(expect, operators.tail)
    case _ =>
      expect match {
        case Plus(_)       => Left(Error.ExpectPlus(operators))
        case Minus(_)      => Left(Error.ExpectMinus(operators))
        case Multiply(_)   => Left(Error.ExpectMultiply(operators))
      }
  }
```

But when I call the function with the following parameter, I get the error as below

```
extract(Plus(_), operators)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error]     |                               Found:    Any => Operator[Any]
[error]     |                               Required: Operator[Any]
```

<strike>Can anyone help me explain why using _ as a parameter is interpreted as Any => [Any]</strike>, is there any way to solve this error?

Here is the snippet: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XLrcrUBvSneJs60w87k43A

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/1d2K7Al6QlmgFHEWjYB6Lw/3 - Which probably means the error is just in your IDE, which means is just a bug in the IDE.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've just updated the question to include the reproduced snippet

Comment: _"Can anyone help me explain why using _ as a parameter is interpreted as Any => [Any]"_ because that is what that syntax does...? is Like asking why `1 + 1 == 2` or why `class` creates a class. - Anyways, so you want to match any `Plus` no matter the tag... the answer is that while possible there are multiple ways and all require some refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a complement to @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's comment and @Gaël J's answer. As stated earlier in the comments and answers, you're actually passing a function, not an `Operator` instance to your extract function. I think what you intended to do, was to use a wildcard for the tag in `Plus` (of course this is not a wildcard, this results in a function). And based on these assumptions, I think what you're looking for is type matching. So this needs a little bit of refactoring, now this code is written in Scala 2, but the concepts should be pretty much applicable to Scala 3 as well:

```scala
// I have defined the Operator as sealed abstract class earlier, and all the subtypes

sealed trait Err[OP <: Operator[_]]
object Err {
  def apply[T <: Operator[_]]: Err[T] = new Err[T] {} // In Scala3 you can easily do type matching here
}

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def extract[A, OperatorType <: Operator[A] : ClassTag](operators: List[Operator[A]]): Either[Err[OperatorType], (Operator[A], List[Operator[A]])] = {
  operators match {
    case (head : OperatorType) :: tail =>
      Right(head, tail)
    case _ => Left(Err[OperatorType])
  }
}

val ops: List[Operator[Int]] = List(Plus(2), Minus(4), Multiply(7))
val shouldFail = extract[Int, Minus[Int]](ops) // fails since first element is not of type Minus
val shouldSucceed = extract[Int, Plus[Int]](ops) // succeeds
```

On [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AminMal/uMtzL2adSSqbE1nMmu2H1g/12).

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is the same as below:

```scala
extract(x => Plus(x), operators)
// Same as:
extract(Plus(_), operators)
```

Meaning `Plus(_)` defines a function, which is not what `extract` expects.